# Иморт базы данных mysql в postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, dump

Как можно залить .sql базу данных в postgresql под рукой только (windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Залить дамп MySQL в postgersql - задача геморройно-нереальная (если, конечно, дамп - не на 2 килобайта).

Предлагаю:

1. Установить MySQL, временно;
2. Развернуть на нём дамп;
3. Сделать дамп только структуры, без данных (mysqldump.exe);
4. Откорректировать дамп структуры вручную и залить его в Postgersql.
5. Сделать выгрузку данных, без структуры, в CSV (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE);
6. Импортировать данные в таблицы из CSV.
7. Деинсталлировать MySQL.

Ещё один вариант - после выполнения п. 4 подключиться к таблицам обеих БД на обоих серверах (например, используя в качестве интерфейса MS Access) и запросами скопировать данные.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать это, например, используя следующую команду:

```
psql <database> < file.sql

где <datatabase> имя используемой базы данных.
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
СТРОКА 1: ALTER TABLE `player`

Идет флуд этими ошибками

Comment: @Михаил, подправь дамп в своём любимом текстовом редакторе (как минимум замени кавычки на нормальные). Если он размером больше пары гигов, то стоит воспользоваться потоковым редактором проде `sed`'а... ЕМНИП под win таких из коробки правда нет...

Comment: @Михаил, У MySQL и PostgreSQL немного отличается синтаксис SQL, так что просто скормить бэкап одной СУБД в другую не получится. Тут нужно конвертер искать какой, либо программно. Подключить обе БД к программе и перенести все таблицы из одной в другую..

Answer (score 0):

Если цель перейти с СУБД MySQL на Postgres: 
рекомендую воспользоватся [специальной утилитой](http://www.convert-in.com/pgskit.htm)

Если цель залить имеющийся дамп MySQL в Postgres лучше все равно воспользоватся утилкой. Так как различия в синтаксисе и типах данных могут помешать просто выполнить SQL.